# Debian Squeeze - PHP5 mysqlnd

Tags: php, mysqli, debian

I'm trying to get mysql native driver support on my new debian squeeze LAMP server and for the life of me I can't get it to work. php mysqli fetch_all is heavily used in my code so I need mysqlnd support. I've installed the php5-mysql package via apt-get which according to everything I've read has support for mysqli but I still cant get fetch_all() to work. There must be something obvious that I'm missing.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use alternative repositories such as:

**DotDeb**

http://dotdeb.org

See "Instructions" page, or download package.

**ONE2TEAM**

http://deb.one2team.ru

(mirror of dotdeb's php5, and some    other php modules)

Answer (score 1):

I was recently looking into this as well.  There doesn't seem to be support for it in the regular Debian packages in Squeeze.  The are adding it to testing and unstable through an alternative package, [php5-mysqlnd](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=php5-mysqlnd).

You could try to find third-party php packages, or you could always build php yourself with support for mysqlnd. This was in a reply from the [package maintainer](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=576412#57).

```
apt-get install php5-dev
cd /tmp
apt-get source php5
cd  /tmp/php5-5.3.6/ext/mysqlnd
mv config9.m4 config.m4
sed -ie "s{ext/mysqlnd/php_mysqlnd_config.h{config.h{" mysqlnd_portability.h
phpize
./configure
cd /tmp/php5-5.3.6/ext/mysql
phpize
./configure --with-mysql=mysqlnd
make && make install
cd /tmp/php5-5.3.6/ext/mysqli
phpize
./configure --with-mysqli=mysqlnd
make && make install
```